# Outlook error in inbox folder / MAPIFolder C# (Microsoft.Office.Interop)

Tags: outlook

i always have the following errors in my inbox:
*Native View    To inspect the native object, enable native code debugging.*

I have the following code:

```
public void CheckForEmails()
{
        Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook._NameSpace _ns = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = _ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        _ns.SendAndReceive(true);


        List<Outlook.MailItem> ReceivedEmail = new List<Outlook.MailItem>();

        Outlook.Items items = inbox.Items;

        foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in inbox.Items)
            ReceivedEmail.Add(mail);
}
```

I have two mail addresses set up in Outlook. 
IMAP and Exchange. 
Perhaps relevant to mention.

Comment: Why do you need to keep a list of `MailItem` objects instead of dealing with the `Items` class?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the `foreach` loop with COM objects. You will not be able to release COM objects in a timely manner and can reach the limit of COM references hold with the Exchange server.

The `Items` class from the Outlook object model is a collection of items that can represent your managed list of emails.